# mod_rewrite not working in xampp in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Xampp on ubuntu 14.04 lts. The mod_rewite feature of xampp is not working.I have rewrite conditions and its depending rewite rule.

Even my apache access log , apache error log and rewrite logs are not generating in the desired path which I mentioned in virtual host file.

my httpd.conf have following lines

```
 ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"
    Listen 80

    #some more modules were also loaded
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">

      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted

    </Directory>
<Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
</Files>

<IfModule dir_module>
    #DirectoryIndex index.html
    # XAMPP
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
</IfModule>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

<IfModule log_config_module>

   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

   <IfModule logio_module>
     # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
   </IfModule>

   CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</IfModule>

EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off

Include etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include etc/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include etc/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
<IfModule ssl_module>
# XAMPP
<IfDefine SSL>
Include etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
</IfDefine>
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

# XAMPP
Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

and my httpd-vhost.conf file have following lines

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "/mnt/logs/apache-error.log"
    CustomLog "/mnt/logs/apache-access.log" combined
    #RewriteLog "/mnt/logs/rewrite.log"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLogLevel 9
    RewriteLog "/mnt/logs/rewrite.log"

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/advertiser/
    RewriteRule ^.*(html|php)  /myProject/advertiser/view/html/index.html 


</VirtualHost>
```

my rewrite rules are not working. I dont know what I am missing.

Comment: have you tried to restart the server?

Comment: ya multiple times

Comment: resolved ..I have to reboot the OS or instance ,then start the server.I know its weird.